# How to print message in vim using python in vimscript

Tags: vim

I am writing a vim plugin using python in vimscript

```
python<<EOF

# python code here

EOF
```

How do I print messages in vim using python in vimscript?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
python<<EOF

print "Hello World!"

EOF
```